# Prevent unauthorized download of files from a webserver

Tags: authentication, php, html

So i have a webserver and i would like to have users login and then be able to download an exe file directly from the webserver the issues with this is that users can easily download the file directly eg "example.com/download/file.exe" bypasssing any authentication, so i need a way using post/get requests to authenticate a user and then allow them to download the file so if a user goes to "example.com/download/file.exe" it will not send them the file but if they go there while providing authentication it will send them the file

thanks in advance for any help, if i havnt explained my issue very well please let me know and ill try clear up any confusion

Comment: this is probably better asked in serverfault or stack overflow.  also what are the capabilities of your web server?

Comment: Ok ill repost it their, also what do you mean the capabilites of my webserver it runs on microsoft azure so it can do alot

Comment: I recommend to close this question and not move it. As currently asked it provides no details about the server which allows others to help (even *"runs on microsoft azure so it can do alot"* from the comment is practically useless on detail). I recommend that the OP makes themselves familiar with what software is in use and then use "authorization" together with the kind of sever (i.e. nginx, apache, iis, ...) to search for the relevant documentation of the server.

Answer (score 1):

In your php script, you can use logic like the following to check if the user is authenticated, then send the file in the response only in this case.  As you can see, the script first sets the appropriate response headers for the filename and content type, then uses the php [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function to output the file.

This way, you can store the file in a directory that is not accessible to the public via your web server, and the web server only outputs the file when the authentication check passes.

```
//set $userauthenticated
//set $contenttype
//set $filename
//set $pathtofile

if($userauthenticated) { 
    Header("Content-type: " . $contenttype);            
    Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");    
    readfile($pathtofile);
}  else {
    print "Unauthorized";
    exit;
}
```